# How many fish heads?

Tags: phrases, expressions, origin-unknown

I am wondering about the origin of the common non sequitur "How many fish heads?". Is it an oblique reference to Douglas Adams'"Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" where when the dolphins leave they say "Goodbye, and thanks for all the fish"? Or is it from something else?

Edit: I have seen this primarily on internet message boards. Also occasionally in conversation, but generally with millennials. [One example](https://i.chzbgr.com/full/3818109440/h11865E27/)

Comment: Where and when have you heard this?  Can you cite an example of usage?

Comment: [A non sequitur is a statement, conclusion or reply that has nothing to do with the previous statement.](http://www.yourdictionary.com/non-sequitur)

Comment: Did you Google "How many fish heads?" before asking here?

Comment: Yes, Barnes & Barnes song? I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*in a loud booming voice* FIVE!

1. [video reference](https://youtu.be/414TmP12WAU?t=57)

Comment: Can you transcribe (or at least describe) the content of the video, so the answer will be useful if the video changes?